# How to migrate es snapshot on aws s3 to on premise

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-s3

This could sound pretty straightforward. However, I've spent days looking in the web for a method where I can migrate snapshot from aws s3 to on premise elasticsearch cluster.

All the docs I've found mentioning how to achieve this for es on cloud, where Kabana console is available. This [doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud/current/ec-migrate-from-aws.html#ec-migrate-from-aws-es-2-2a) for instance is an example.

Can anyone advise me how can I achieve this? noting that:

Snapshot taken, and a repo already exist within aws s3 bucket. 7

O.S: Centos 7

Answer (score 0):

If you repo already exists in S3, you can register that same repo with your on-premise Elasticsearch cluster using [S3 repository plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/repository-s3.html#repository-s3).

This plugin once installed in your on-premise ES (and making sure you have a clear network path between ES and S3) will help you to list and restore snapshots you would have taken using your AWS Elasticsearch cluster.